# Javascript doesn't show a generated number? (document.getElementById)

Tags: javascript, html

I want num1 and num2 to generate as a random number from 1-12, when I run it, I only get 2+2.

Here is what I think is wrong with my code

```js
function generate_equation() { //generates random numbers and random equation
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random) * 13;
  var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random) * 13;

  var all_answers = [];
  var switch_answers = [];

  answer = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById(num1).innerHTML = num1;
  document.getElementById(num2).innerHTML = num2;
}
```

```html
<div class="equation">
  <h1 id="num1" style="padding: 0 5px">2</h1>
  <h1 id="operator" style="padding: 0 5px">+</h1>
  <h1 id="num2" style="padding: 0 5px">2</h1>
</div>
```

Here's a link to the full code, not everything is finished due to some circumstances with college.
https://jsfiddle.net/LiamBox/f406mgpb/3/

Comment: Where are you even calling your function? We need a [mcve] and it has to be here, not on another site

Comment: `getElementById(num1)` should be `getElementById("num1")`, `Math.random` should be  `Math.random()`. I'd work a bit slower, line by line in small chunks, and `console.log` everything at each step to make sure it works as you expect instead of blazing ahead and winding up with multiple issues. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)` -- the `floor` should wrap the whole thing, otherwise you'll always get 0. I recommend [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Pro-tip: a lot of the issues you've encountered can be easily debugged if you open your browser console :) it's a very helpful tool to find out why your script isn't executing or throwing errors, since the error messages often contain enough information to help you debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 problems with your code:

1. Your usage of `Math.floor` and `Math.random` isn't quite right. Calling `Math.floor(Math.random)` is just going to pass the function itself to `floor`. You probably want `Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)`
2. Your code is all inside of a function that doesn't get called. You'll need to invoke it somewhere or move it out of the function so it's run when the page is loaded.
3. id needs to be a string - the way you used it `num1` is being interpreted as a local variable name, which due to unfortunate naming, contains the random number generated.

```js
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
  var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
  
 

  var all_answers = [];
  var switch_answers = [];

  answer = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = num1;
  document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = num2;
```

```html
<div class="equation">
  <h1 id="num1" style="padding: 0 5px">2</h1>
  <h1 id="operator" style="padding: 0 5px">+</h1>
  <h1 id="num2" style="padding: 0 5px">2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right I did the whole Math.floor & Math.random completely wrong. As you said, I'll see what I can do to call the function when The page loads, including naming the id as a string

Answer (score 0):

**This solution assigns DOM elements to global variables, and uses a supporting function** to better follow the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.

And **below the snippet you'll find a step-by-step description of how you might start debugging** your original code.

```js
// Identifies some DOM elements
const
  h1_num1 = document.getElementById("num1"),
  h1_num2 = document.getElementById("num2"),
  h1_answer = document.getElementById("answer");

// Invokes main function
generate_equation();


// Defines main function
function generate_equation() { 
  
  // Generates random numbers (using supporting function), and gets their sum
  const
    num1 = randIntBelow(13),
    num2 = randIntBelow(13),
    sum = num1 + num2;

  // Populates the elements
  h1_num1.innerHTML = num1;
  h1_num2.innerHTML = num2;
  h1_answer.innerHTML = sum;
}


// Defines supporting function
function randIntBelow(limit){
  const
    rand_num_below_limit = Math.random() * limit,
    integer_part = Math.floor(rand_num_below_limit);
  return integer_part;
}
```

```css
/* Using CSS to keep styling separate from structure
     makes HTML less repetetive and more maintainable */
h1{ padding: 0 5px; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="equation">
  <h1 id="num1"></h1>
  <h1 id="operator">+</h1>
  <h1 id="num2"></h1>
  <h1 id="equals">=</h1>
  <h1 id="answer"></h1>  
</div>
```

---

**Here's how you'd begin to get from your original code to something more like the above:**

- If you run your code in your browser and **open the browser console**, you should see an error message with information something like:

  `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') ... line 26 ...`,

  meaning that on line 26, you're asking JavaScript for the `innerHTML` property of something that has no such property (because it is `null`).
- **Checking the indicated line**, you'd see:

  `document.getElementById(num1).innerHTML = num1;`

  so "document.getElementById(num1)" must evaluate to `null` ... meaning JavaScript can't find an element whose `id` matches the value stored in the variable called `num1`
- If you wanted to learn what `num1` evaluates to, you'd add a simple line like `console.log(num1);` to your script and refresh your browser -- but in this case, you might already see in the code that **`num1` is expected to hold a random number, not an `id` string.**
- **So you'd change your code to pass a more appropriate argument** to `.getElementById()` -- then refresh your browser to see the next error message **and repeat** this debugging process until there are no more errors to conquer.